# Create a reusable list in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am rather new to AngularJS and am trying to create a **reusable list of any kind of entity** (e.g.: todo, contacts, and so on). Each entity type should have a different kind of presentation. Furthermore, this list should be sortable by any attributes defined in a dedicated entity controller.

I was able to achieve this with the following markup:

```
<entitylist>

    <entitylist:orderby>
        <option value="created">Created</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
    </entitylist:orderby>

    <entitylist:items>
        <entitylist:item ng-repeat="entity in entities | orderBy:orderby" ng-click="showDetails(entity)">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="entity.completed"/> {{ entity.title }}
        </entitylist:item>
    </entitylist:items>

</entitylist>
```

But it seemed redundant to use this template for each entity type. I then tried something like this (entity template):

```
<entitylist sortable="sortable" entities="todos">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="entity.completed"/> {{ entity.title }}
</entitylist>
```

With the following directive:

```
angular.module('app.components')

    .directive('entitylist', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'EntityListController',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/entitylist/entitylist.tpl.html',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                entities: '='
            }
        };
    })

    .controller('EntityListController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.orderby = $scope.$parent.orderby;
        $scope.sortable = $scope.$parent.sortable;
    }])

;
```

The controller In a ui-router state):

```
controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'entities',
    function( $scope,   $state,   entities) {
        $scope.todos = entities;
        $scope.orderby = 'name';
        $scope.sortable = [{value: 'name', name: 'Name'}, {value: 'created', name: 'Created'}];
    }
]
```

And the directive template (components/entitylist/entitylist.tpl.html):

```
<div class="entitylist">

    <div class="entitylist-nav">

        <select ng-model="orderby" class="form-control">
            <option ng-repeat="sort in sortable" value="sort.value">{{ sort.name }}</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <ul class="entity-list">
        <li ng-repeat="entity in entities | orderBy:orderby">
            <div ng-transclude=""></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

But here I was struggling for hours with isolated scopes of ng-repeat and ng-transclude and was not able to make that work. I created a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U8VQ/1/)**.

My question is: am I on the right track? What's the angular way of achieving something like this? I've been googling for days to find anything relevant, but had no success. Are there any examples of this (apart from single list tutorials)?

Comment: Let's see the code for your `entitylist` directives

Comment: I had the feeling it would be more helpful to me to get some pseudo "best practice angular way" or examples instead of talking about my controllers and directives (that I am not proud of). But I have updated my question with some more code.

Comment: What you're after (a generic list UI) isn't out of the question.  I know that the doubleclick team (doubleclick is probably the largest angularjs application out there) use generic list controllers in their app.  You mentioned isolated scope issues, which is why I asked to see the code.

Comment: Respectively, is it wise to do something that i tried to do in my second markup approach: using a transcluded content, that will be repeated, in a directive, or are there any other proper ways?

Comment: That approach sounds valid.  See this fiddle I just threw together: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/HD6K8/

Comment: Aha! It seems that there is a difference between angular 1.2.1 and 1.2.18: http://jsfiddle.net/5U8VQ/2/ (1.2.18: not working) http://jsfiddle.net/5U8VQ/3/ (1.2.1: working)

Comment: It's looking pretty slick.  Added 'reverse': http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/59nNK/